# How to test if my video card has 3D support?

Tags: hardware, graphics

How can I test if my video card has 3D support?

Someone told to use `fgl_glxgears`, but it does not exist here, not even for installation with apt-get.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a topic with a *lot* of bad/outdated/incorrect information available.

Things which *don't* work:

- Checking for "direct rendering: Yes":
  This isn't an accurate indicator.  The software renderer *also* supports direct rendering, so even if you don't have hardware 3D support you can have `direct rendering: Yes`
- Checking the FPS of `glxgears`:
  This isn't an accurate indicator either.  Recent versions of Ubuntu will have vsync enabled, so `glxgears` will only run as fast as the screen refresh rate.  This means `glxgears` will almost always print an FPS of `60` or thereabouts.

What *does* work:

The output of `glxinfo` contains the information we want.

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
… snip …
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
… snip long extensions list…
```

The **OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset** line indicates that I'm using my Intel GM45 chip to do 3D rendering.

**OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.1** indicates the baseline OpenGL version that this driver/hardware supports (OpenGL 2.1) and the version of Mesa being used (7.10.1).

Finally, **direct rendering: Yes** *on top of the previous two fields* indicates that the driver is working properly with a direct rendering context.  This will never be **No** unless something is really messed up with your install (or you're doing something strange, like connecting to a remote X server).

Examples of bad `glxinfo` output:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture,
```

Here we've got no hardware acceleration, so the `Software Rasterizer` is providing (slow!) 3D support.

```
 LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=foo glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 7.10.1)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_fragment_program,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture,
```

Here we've broken direct rendering by pointing LIBGL at a non-existent DRIVERS_PATH. The direct rendering pathway fails:

```
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
```

But indirect rendering is still working, because the display server has loaded the driver

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 7.10.1)
```

(Note that the OpenGL version advertised is now OpenGL 1.4 - this is the newest OpenGL version for which there is an indirect rendering protocol).

Comment: Hey, man :)
So - I have the `bad` glxinfo output. Then - how can i set the `DRIVERS_PATH` variable? And to what should I set it? I have intel graphcis and intel driver installed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `glxgears` instead, or `glxinfo`.

Comment: cool.. if I see the gears means I have support for 3d?

Comment: Yes, exactly.:)

Comment: Well, kinda.  Because we've got a software renderer you'll need to have messed up your system pretty badly before glxgears will be broken so badly that it won't display the gears!

Comment: I also see the gears, but at the same I have complains from some apps, games specifically ... Can you please take a look?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174810/driver-for-intel-hd-installed-but-still-games-complain-3d-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

With `glxgears` you can see gears, and **AMD users** can use to configure the graphic properties:

```
sudo amdcccle
```