# Driver for Intel HD installed, but still games complain 3D is not supported

Tags: games, intel-graphics, 3d

I'm trying to run several Blizzard games, but they all complain with my graphics driver.

Here is some info:

```
$ > glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_no_config_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float,
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)  (0x5917)
    Version: 18.3.2
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.3.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth,
    GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64, GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect,
    GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,
    GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax,
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    ...........
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth,
    GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
    ....
```

Also:

```
$ sudo hwinfo --gfxcard
13: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)              
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: _Znp.e3wbDZ8BKEA
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "Intel UHD Graphics 620"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x5917 "UHD Graphics 620"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1558 "CLEVO/KAPOK Computer"
  SubDevice: pci 0x1413
  Revision: 0x07
  Driver: "i915"
  Driver Modules: "i915"
  Memory Range: 0xdb000000-0xdbffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x90000000-0x9fffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xf000-0xf03f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 16 (110055 events)
  I/O Ports: 0x3c0-0x3df (rw)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00005917sv00001558sd00001413bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i915 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

Primary display adapter: #13
```

And also:

```
$ inxi -Gxx
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5917 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:5917
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.3 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.05hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.3.2 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
```

However, I get `Your 3D accelerator card is not supported by World of Warcraft` or (for Warcraft 3) - `Unable to initialize graphics. Please ensure your operating system and display drivers are up to date.`

From what I read - the problem is that `Mesa` is not loading the appropriate graphics driver. But I don't know how to fix this.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks